# Volley request onFinish() method removed?

Tags: android, android-volley

We just updated from volley ver 1.0.19 to 1.1.1.  In classes that extend the Request class, we were overriding the onFinish() method.

Since the update, it looks like that method is gone.

How do we catch this or a similar callback now?

Answer (score 0):

The **RequestQueue** on which your **Request** is executed has *addRequestFinishedListener(listener)* which you might use - the listener is called when the **Request** finishes.